# How to install and run docker on Google collab?

Tags: docker, google-colaboratory, nvidia, large-language-model, tensorrt

I wish to run this https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/optimizing-inference-on-llms-with-tensorrt-llm-now-publicly-available/ on google collab but unable to run docker after installing it not sure wether i have installed correcttly.
Can someone help me out here. I read somewhere that google collab doest not fully support docker, however, is there any workaround?

I tried this refering to https://gist.github.com/mwufi/6718b30761cd109f9aff04c5144eb885

```
sudo apt update -qq

sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common -qq

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"

sudo apt update -qq

sudo apt install docker-ce

docker
```

and if is check !docker --version - it says : Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
So i am assuming that docker is installed.
But unable to start docker